# Dropdownlist that is populated by javascript gets reset after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using js function to add items in dropdownlist.All items are added perfectly but when I want to add selected value from that in DB,On clicking button the dropdownlist gets reset on postback.

How can I stop this?

Comment: I think you would have to go by `Request.Form["dropdownid"]` to get the value and after postback you will have to push in the values again since you added them to the html control part and not the asp net as an ListItem

Comment: items added using js to dropdown will get removed because asp.net didn't find items in its ViewState when postback.. i think you should try consider AJAX if you can..

Comment: @SupriyaSrivastava Does it get reset, or is the selected value constant? (i.e always equal to the first item)

Comment: @V4Vendetta k,thnks for solution but how will I get the Text of selected item.

Comment: @Shai Actually,I am unable to read items which are added through js.

Comment: ok. what do you want in your code behind? items added to dropdownlist or only the selected text/value?

Comment: @SupriyaSrivastava well its got to be part of the value then

Comment: I want to ask something; why are you using javascript to fill a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are lost on postback because they are added client side through javascript, and do not exist in viewstate.

An option would be to add an `<asp:hiddenfield />`, and add some javascript code to the `onChange` event of your dropdown to write the selectedvalue into the hiddenfield input. This value will then be accesible after postback. You still have to re-populate the dropdown again after postback though.

Example:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="DropDownValue" runat="server" />
<select onChange='document.getElementById("<%= DropDownValue.ClientID %>").value = this.value;'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I got data for ddl through ajax. In my case I populate DDL with the same data which I got on client on every postback in Page_Init(...)